# Converting csv to excel PHP

Tags: php, json, excel, csv

I'm generating a `csv` file through JSON in my application. But when I open it, it's not formatted.
Is there any script available in PHP to convert from `csv` to `Excel`?

My output now is:

```
,"12","1","1","","","","","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","","","0","","","","0","0","0"2121","0","","1","1","","","non","210,"0","0","0","0","07:00","","","0","","",
```

Comment: PHPExcel http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: You want to import the data with excels data function and not convert it with PHP into anything.

Comment: There's plenty, biziclop has given you a link to the best

Answer (score 0):

Just open the csv in Excel....

You should be all fine and dandy ^_^

No need to "convert" it.